# How can I allow a non administrator account to enable/disable/configure wireless network settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, wifi

I have a user in our domain on a Dell laptop using windows 7 professional. Occasionally, she needs to switch from wired to wireless, but currently the system denies her this privledge without an administrator password. Is there a way to enable her to manage wireless settings? I have no group policies that should be limiting her ability in this area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you are on a Windows Server 2008 domain.

Create a new policy under user configuration> Administrative Templates> Network> Network connections

Look for this policy

**Ability to enable/disable a LAN Connection**

Determines whether users can enable/disable LAN connections.
If you enable this setting, the Enable and Disable options for LAN connections are available to users (including nonadministrators). Users can enable/disable a LAN connection by double-clicking the icon representing the connection, by right-clicking it, or by using the File menu.

If you disable this setting (and enable the "Enable Network Connections settings for Administrators" setting), double-clicking the icon has no effect, and the Enable and Disable menu items are disabled for all users (including administrators).
Important: If the "Enable Network Connections settings for Administrators" is disabled or not configured, this setting will not apply to administrators on post-Windows 2000 computers.

If you do not configure this setting, only Administrators and Network Configuration Operators can enable/disable LAN connections.
Note: Administrators can still enable/disable LAN connections from Device Manager when this setting is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need to do is make sure she is part of the [Network Configuration Operators Group](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297938).  This group enables you to delegate the privileges that can manage the configuration of networking features

Answer (score 0):

One of the following:

1) Notebooks typically have a utility to turn the wireless transceiver on/off (to save energy). And wired interface is effectively switched off by unplugging the cable. With both interfaces on auto-configuration, this should work if the utility doesn't require administrative privileges.

2) Make her a local administrator (add the domain user to the local Administrators group) or create a local administrator user with a known password. Changing a server's network connectivity is really an administrator's prerogative. This solution is typical in IT companies where users can, want and need to install software, change system settings etc; GPO-imposed limitations will still apply.

3) Write a script to enable/disable the interfaces (in Vista+, WMI can do this, see [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Enable or Disable My Network Adapter?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/29/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-my-network-adapter.aspx); in XP, you'll have to resort to a more frightening Win32 API, see [c# - Win32 API function to programatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device)) and use something like [Sudo for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/) to run it with elevated privileges without entering admin password.